# Why my Laravel Application still finding the older database name?

Tags: php, database, laravel, caching

For example, I have `DB_DATABASE=new_db` in my .env file and the same as the `config/database.php` file but still showing error of `Unknown database: 'older_database_name'.` Please help. Thanks.

Anyway I migrated from MAMP to XAMPP..

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Try php artisan config:cache  it would clear your config cache and cache the new config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restart the server if any changes on .env

try `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan cache:clear`